# How can I stop a teleporting enemy?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I'm currently playing a 7th level Fighter in a Pathfinder campaign.  My character is built around controlling movement as much as possible in Pathfinder.  Since the campaign is *Wrath of the Righteous* we of course face more than the normal number of Evil Outsiders. This leads me to want to be able to counter or stop teleportation.

I plan on taking [**Teleport Tactician**](http://paizo.com/PRD/advanced/advancedFeats.html#teleport-tactician) at 11th level, but it doesn't necessarily allow me to *stop* teleport.  Is there any way, preferably item based, to *stop* a teleportation attempt with an attack of opportunity?

Comment: By the way, depending on how your GM wants to rule it, it might be possible to get two AoOs from Teleport Tactician if a teleport both enters and leaves a threatened square.  Ask him - I don't think RAW technically supports it, but I like it, especially since it has the flavor of that one Riddick movie...  and I'm assuming your build already includes Combat Patrol to make your AoOs super-useful.

Comment: related (although not really item - based answers, but it contains some of them): http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/35853/way-to-prevent-teleportation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the [Phase Locking](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/phase-locking) weapon enchant (+2 equivalent) will *dimensional anchor* someone it hits for a round. That's the most general answer.

There's others that have their pros and cons:

- [Kyton Scourge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/specific-magic-weapons/kyton-scourge) (a specific whip good for fighting Cenobites)
- [Demonsorrow Curve Blade](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/specific-magic-weapons/demonsorrow-curve-blade) (does it in a radius, and it's +3 cold iron holy demonbane - save up your gold, it's nearly $100k!!!)
- [Dimensional Shackles](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/c-d/dimensional-shackles) (do that trick from that magician movie)

Comment: What check would be used to apply Dimensional Shackles?

Comment: Sleight of Hand DC30!  Or maybe a grapple and pin... You know, make it up!